# Passing dynamic arguments to service factory in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-dependency-injection

I'm integrating Symfony into an older application having its own dependency container based on PSR-11. Been searching for a solution to merge that DI container to the one Symfony uses, but found nothing. To just make it work, I came with one "hacky" solution which I don't like.

I've created this class. It creates an instance of an old DI container inside of it:

```php
class OldAppServiceFactory
{
    private ContainerInterface $container;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->container = OldContainerFactory::create();
    }

    public function factory(string $className)
    {
        return $this->container->get($className);
    }
}
```

and added proper entries to `services.yaml`:

```yaml
    oldapp.service_factory:
        class: Next\Service\LeonContainer\LeonServiceFactory

    OldApp\Repository\Repository1:
        factory: ['@oldapp.service_factory', 'factory']
        arguments:
            - 'OldApp\Repository\Repository1'

    OldApp\Repository\Repository2:
        factory: ['@oldapp.service_factory', 'factory']
        arguments:
            - 'OldApp\Repository\Repository2'

    OldApp\configuration\ConfigurationProviderInterface:
        factory: ['@oldapp.service_factory', 'factory']
        arguments:
            - 'OldApp\configuration\ConfigurationProviderInterface'
```

With above hack, putting those classes in service class constructors works. Unfortunately it looks bad and it'll be pain to extend it with more of those repositories (especially when having 50 of them). Is it possible to achieve something like this in `services.yaml`?

```yaml
    OldApp\Repository\:
        factory: ['@oldapp.service_factory', 'factory']
        arguments:
            - << PASS FQCN HERE >>
```

This would leave me with only one entry in `services.yaml` for a single namespace of the old application.

But, maybe there is other solution for my problem? Been trying with configuring `Kernel.php` and `prepareContainer(...)` method, but I also ended with nothing as the old dependencies are in one PHP file returning an array:

```php
return array [
    RepositoryMetadataCache::class => static fn () => RepositoryMetadataCache::createFromCacheFile(),
    EntityCollection::class => autowire(EntityCollection::class),
    'Model\Repository\*' => static function (ContainerInterface $container, RequestedEntry $entry) { ... }
];
```

Comment: @yivi I'll check your answer for sure! Didn't have a free moment to do it, yet. Thank you for taking your time on this . As for the `OldApp` namespace: I've made Symfony in a totally different namespace, so probably there will be no issue with it as I have `\OldApp\*` and `\NewApp\*` being in different directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably accomplish this easily with a custom compiler pass.

First tag all the old repository classes by loading the directory where they exist:

```yaml
OldApp\Repository\:
    resource: '../src/OldApp/Repository/*'
    autowire: false
    autoconfigure: false
    tags: ['oldapp_repository']
```

(I think that you may need to also exclude `src/OldApp` from the default automatic service loading. E.g.:

```yaml
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{OldApp/Repository,DependencyInjection,Entity,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

... but I'm not 100% sure, test this one).

Then create a compiler pass to go through the tags and define a factory for each one:

```php
class OldAppRepositoryCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('oldapp_repository');

        foreach ($taggedServices as $serviceId => $tags) {

            $definition = $container->getDefinition($serviceId);
            $definition
                    ->setFactory([new Reference('oldapp.service_factory'), 'factory'])
                    ->addArgument($serviceId);
        }

    }
}
```

And in your Application Kernel `build()` method add the compiler pass:

```php
// src/Kernel.php
namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
// ...

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    // ...

    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new OldAppRepositoryCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

Can't test this right at this minute, but this should get you going in the right direction. For additional details check the docs:

- [Working with service tags](https://symfony.com/index.php/doc/current/service_container/tags.html)

You can check [this example repo](https://github.com/yivi/so_qa_70290903) where the above is implemented and working. On this repo the `OldApp` namespace is outside of `App` and `src`,  so no need to exclude it from automatic service loading.

Comment: It works! Thank you! The only one thing to change in your code is this `new Reference('@oldapp.service_factory')` should be without the `@` character :). Wasn't working for me with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix the answer. I usually use fully-qualified-class-names as service ids, so that one got by me.